# Number of walks

Tags: co.combinatorics

How many walks (asymptotically) of length $2n$ with up or right steps from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ are there such that the walk is always between the lines $y=x+k$ and $y=x-k$?

Comment: An exact formula in which the largest term gives an asymptotic formula is formula (5) of http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/artikel/encystat.pdf.

Comment: The asymptotics of your number  as $n\to \infty$  and $k$ is fixed  is $C_k (2\rho_k)^{2n}$, where $\rho_k=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2k+2})$. See details in the updates to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number is very small. Here is a possible approach.     Here we assume $n\gg k$ and we denote a walk with the constraints you mention as *admissible*.    Given any walk  of length $L$  and $j\in \{1,\dotsc, L\}$  we denote by  $(H_j, V_j)$ the location at time $j$. Thus $H_j$ is the number of horizontal steps taken up to the moment $j$ and similarly, and $V_j$ is the number  of vertical steps taken up to the time $j$. A path is admissible if $-k\leq V_j-H_j\leq k$, $\forall j$. $V_{2n}=H_{2n}=n$.

To a walk $W$  in the lattice $\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$ $\bZ^2$ we  associate a walk $W'$  in the lattice $\bZ$  starting at $0$ as $0$. If at time  $j$ in $W$  we take a vertical steps, then in $W'$ we move one unit to the right. If at time $j$ in $W$ we take a horizontal step, then in  $W'$ we take a step to the left.

Now think of the walks in $\mathbb{Z}^2$  as random walks where the  horizontal/vertical steps  have the same probability.    We have thus associated to a random walk $W$ in $\bZ^2$ a standard one-dimensional  walk $W'$ on $\bZ$. The walk $W$ is admissible if and only if the corresponding walk $W'$ starts and ends  at $0$ and never leaves the   interval $[-k,k]$.   Denote by $T(W')$ the first moment steps outside the interval $[-k,k]$.  The probability that $T(W')> 2n$ is known.     Walks in the interval $[-k-1,k+1]$ with absorbing boundary seem relevant. (I have to leave.)

**Edit.** Had a busy weekend. I have two comments.

**1.** *Ira Gessels's   comment answers the original question more precisely than my speculations above.*

**2.**  *My above speculations can still be used to  provide an asymptotic  estimate  for $n$ large.  More precisely if $W_k(n)$ is the number of walks from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that do not cross the lines $y=x\pm k$, then*

$$ W_k(n)\sim \left(\;  2\cos\frac{\pi}{2k+2}\;\right)^{2n}\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;n\to \infty. $$

*This approach  also yields an explicit expression in terms of Chebyshev polynomials for the generating function of the number of walks from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that do cross the lines $y=x\pm k$; see (3).  Here are the details.*

Denote by $p_k(n)$ the probability that  a random walk on $\bZ$ starts and ends  at $0$ after $2n$ steps  and never  reaches the locations $\pm(k+1)$. Form the generating series

$$ P_k(x)=:\sum_{n\geq 0} p_k(n)x^{2n}. $$

Using the  idea  of the random walk on $[-(k+1),(k+1)]$ with absorbing boundary one can give an explicit description of $P_k(x)$ as a  *rational* function.

For any natural number $m$ denote by $Q_m$ the $m\times m$  symmetric matrix with entries

$$q_{ij}=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, &|i-j|=1\\
0, & |i-j|\neq 1.
\end{cases}. $$

Then $p_k(n)$ is equal to the $(k+1,k+)$-entry of the matrix $Q_{2k+1}^{2n}$, i.e., the   entry of this odd-sized matrix located dead in the center. (This is not hard to see. Alternatively, check any book on Markov chains. $Q$ corresponds to the transient part of this Markov chain.)

This shows that  $P_k(x)$ is the $(k+1,k+1)$ entry of the matrix $(1-xQ)^{-1}$  and from the expression of a the entries of the inverse of a matrix in terms of the minors of the matrix we deduce

$$P_k(x)=\frac{\det(1-xQ_k)^2}{\det(1-xQ_{2k+1})}. $$

The special shape of the matrices  $Q_m$  leads to a recursive computations of the determinants of $1-xQ_m$. Hint: the matrix $1-xQ_m$ is a *Jacobi matrix* and,  if $D_m(x):=\det(1-xQ_m)$, then

$$D_m(x)=D_{m-1}(x)-\frac{x^2}{4} D_{m-2}(x). $$

This leads to an explicit, albeit  complicated  expression of $P_k(x)$ in terms of Chebyshev polynomials; see (2).

In any case the above  expression shows that  the asymptotic behavior of $p_{k}(n)$ is determined by  the eigenvalues of $Q_{2k+1}$. It is not hard to see that the spectrum of this symmetric matrix is contained   in $(-1,1)$.  $\DeclareMathOperator{\spec}{spec}$  If

$$\Lambda_k=\max\bigl\{\; |\lambda|;\;\;\lambda\in\spec(Q_{2k+1})\;\bigr\}<1,  $$

then we deduce that

$$ p_k(n)=O(\Lambda_k^{2n}), \;\;n\to\infty. $$

I believe that

$$p_k(n) \sim C_k\Lambda_k^{2n}, $$

so the asymptotics of the number of walks you asked about would be

$$\sim C (2\Lambda_k)^{2n}. $$

The spectrum of $Q_m$  is known. More precisely

$$\spec Q_m =\Bigl\{ \cos \frac{k\pi}{m+1};\;\;k=1,\dotsc, m\;\Bigr\}. $$

For details see  [these beautiful answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91161/eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues-of-tridiagonal-matrix/91229#91229) to a MO question.  Thus

$$ p_k(n) \sim C_k\Bigl(\cos\frac{\pi}{2k+2}\Bigr)^{2n}, \tag{1} $$

for some constant $C_k$   described explicitly in (4) below.

**Remark.**  Let us denote by $W_k(n)$ the number of East-North   walks in the lattice $\bZ^2$ which start at $(0,0)$, end at $(n,n)$ and do not cross the lines $y=x\pm k$. We form the generating series

$$W_k(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} W_k(n)x^{2n}. $$

Then

$$W_k(x) =P_k(2x). $$

Let us express $P_k(x)$ in terms of the characteristic polynomials $\Delta_m(x)$ of the matrices $Q_m$. We have

$$D_m(x)=\det(1-xQ_m)= x^m \det(x^{-1}-Q_m) =x^m \Delta_m(x^{-1}). $$

We have

$$\Delta_m(x)= x\Delta_{m-1}(x)-\frac{1}{4}\Delta_{m-2}(x). $$

In particular, if $S_m(x)=2^{m} \Delta_m(x)$,  then we deduce that

$$S_m(x)= 2xS_{m-1}(x) -S_{m-2}(x). $$

This is precisely the recurrence relation satisfied by the Chebyshev polynomials $T_m(x)$, $U_m(x)$ defined by

$$ T_m(\cos \theta)=\cos(m\theta),\;\;U_m(\cos\theta)=\frac{\sin(m+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}. $$

Note that

$$ S_1(x) =2x=U_1(x), \;\; S_2(x)=4x^2-1=U_2(x). $$

Hence $S_m(x)=U_m(x)$ so that

$$\Delta_m(x)=\frac{1}{2^m} U_m(x),\;\; D_m(x)=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m U_m(1/x), $$

$$ D_m(2x)= x^m U_m\left(\frac{1}{2x}\right), $$

$$P_k(x)=\frac{4}{x^2}\frac{U_k(1/x)^2}{U_{2k+2}(1/x)},\;\;\tag{2} $$

$$  W_k(x)= \frac{U_{k}\bigl(\frac{1}{2x}\bigr)^2}{x^2 U_{2k+2}\bigl(\frac{1}{2x}\bigr)}. \tag{3} $$

We can say something about the constant $C_k$ in (1) by observing that

$$ D_m(x) =A_m\prod_{j=1}^m\left(1-x\cos\frac{j\pi}{m+1}\right), $$

for some constant $A_m$.  More precisely

$$ A_m=2^{-m}\times \mbox{ the leading coefficient of $U_m$}=1.$$

Then

$$ P_k(x)= \frac{A_k^2}{A_{2k+2}}\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k (1-x\cos\frac{j\pi}{k+1})}{\prod_{\ell=1}^{k+1}(1-x\cos \frac{(2\ell-1)\pi}{2k+2})}. $$

This shows that

$$ C_k=\frac{A_k^2}{A_{2k+2}}=1.\tag{4} $$

**Update 2.** As I suspected all along, this problem has been thoroughly investigated.  There is a comprehensive discussion of this and other problems in  Chapter XIV, Sect. 4,5  vol 1 of Feller's book. This problem  also makes its appearance in  the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistics test; see  Chap I, Sec. 12, vol. 2 of Feller's book on probability., or Feller's article **On the Kolmogorov-Smirnov limit theorems for empirical distributions**, Ann. Math. Statistics, 19(1948), 177-189.